# How to color code scatter-plot of PCoA

Tags: r, pca, scatter-plot, multivariate-testing, multivariate-partition

So I am new to this. I need to run PCoA on the following data matrix. I am able to run my analyses using ADE4, labdsv, Ginko, Aabel softwares. Whats bothering me is how to color code the labels in the scatter plot. My matrix is a presence/absence matrix in the order:

```
SpecieName Value1 Value2
A1         0      1
A2         1      1
A3         1      1
B1         0      0
B2         0      1
E1         1      0
E2         0      0
```

What I want is to represent `A1`, `A2`, and `A3` in red, `B1` and `B2` in Blue and all the `E` ones in black. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass in a factor that denotes these groups to the plotting command:

```
data = read.table('data.txt', header=T)

data.pca = prcomp(data[,-1])

groups = factor(gsub('(.).', '\\1', data$SpecieName))

plot(data.pca$x, col=groups)
```

[image]

Also, if you want to set *specific* colors, you can always index into a custom list the same way:

```
cols = c('red', 'blue', 'black')[groups]
plot(data.pca$x, col=cols)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, my matrix is like a distance matrix (n*n). I am using cmdscale(distance_matrix, k) to run a Principal Coordinate Analysis (PCoA). So in my distance matrix, I have specie names on both the first row and first column. I use scatter to show me the PCoA object returned by cmdscale and I see my species plotted in the way I want. But do not know how to color code them. Will the answer you provided work for distance matrices as well? I am an absoulte beginner in R

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Yes, this is the standard way to supply colors to most R plotting commands. Good luck!

Comment: What does this line do? data.pca = prcomp(data[,-1])

Comment: Is it possible to add a legend?